# What one word means “unable to decide which one is correct”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to find one single word in English that means “unable to decide which one is correct”.

Comment: "Right" meaning true, or just preferred? Please provide additional information about how this word would be used.

Comment: Hi @Mae! Have you looked anywhere for this? Or did you have any ideas that might fit or nearly so? Let us know, so that we can give you a better answer!

Comment: "right" here meaning true/correct

Comment: Hello, Matt: I tried but failed to find any.

Comment: OK, that's a great start. If you could edit your question just to let us know where you looked, that could help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Mae: I encourage you to use your [registered account](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/84785/mae) exclusively. That way you will be able to edit your own posts without needing to go through the review process. Also, when you ask a question and then provide additional, clarifying information that is legitimately part of the question, just go straight for the [Edit]. Please don’t post an answer containing an appendix to your question.

Answer (score 1):

undecided,  unresolved,  floating, uncertain  ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **[conflicted](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conflicted)**. According to *Collins English Dictionary*

> relating to or experiencing mental conflict; unable to decide between opposing feelings or views;*to be conflicted about something*

Answer (score 0):

The word “conflicted” is rather close, yet it does not quite reflect on the need for a person “to be able to decide which one is right/correct”. Perhaps the scenario below may help to find a closer word than “conflicted”.

Scenario:
After a traffic accident, a policeman heard very divergent descriptions from a few witnesses, and he was unable to decide which description was correct. There must be a word to express one’s feeling of being “unable to decide which one is correct”.

Comment: Perhaps "uncertain" or "undecided" is the best match, then.